# How do I save a workbook when a specific cell is selected using VBA?

Tags: excel, save, vba

I am trying to make a workbook save automatically, using VBA, when I click on a certain cell, or an array of cells rather.

I am using a spreadsheet to log data and when I press enter to move down to the next cell I want the workbook to be saved automatically so, that in a case that the power goes out or my computer crashes, the data is saved as it is being input.

Also, what is the code to save document when a macro button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

If you put this at the sheet level it will fire every time that event happens:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 Then ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

The column = 2 part is telling it to only fire when the second column (Column B) is what changes, you can put any sort of cell range you like in here using target.column, target.row or target.address